# How to pick nested types which maybe have null-able parents

Tags: typescript

I'm auto-generating my GraphQL types with [graphql-code-gen](https://graphql-code-generator.com/) and get something like this:

```js
type Maybe<T> = T | null;

type Project = {
  id: string
}

type Milestone = {
  id: string
  title: string
  startDate: number
  endDate: number
}

type Foobar = (
  { __typename?: 'Query' }
  & { project: Maybe<(
    { __typename?: 'Project' }
    & Pick<Project, 'id'>
    & { milestones: (
      { __typename?: 'MilestoneConnection' }
      & { edges: Array<(
        { __typename?: 'MilestoneEdge' }
        & { node: (
          { __typename?: 'Milestone' }
          & Pick<Milestone, 'id' | 'title' | 'startDate' | 'endDate'>
        ) }
      )> }
    ) }
  )> }
);

const foo: Foobar['project']['milestones']
```

I can't access `milestones` because `project` may be null. Is there any possibility to get everything that's defined for `milestone` nevertheless?

[TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=32&pc=43#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCyBDRAjYAeAFQD44BeOAuAHzgDsBXAG0YG4AoNpFOABSggBWwAMbxyAbzZw4ASwAmALjgBnGFBm0A5mwC+HLqjQzGwVRFqoJU2YpVqN26TBkwTS1eq3XVGWABEMGGAlBgBbXChrYFo5AKCQ+nDgSL1OZFQAMQgIbF8yOAAKa3E4AH1Sg1oMUOAAfiUAcgBFemTEBrg9aQAyOBKwfiFRJUwcfCLpaRLyyuq6xr5BERgOrsnenhlhAGs8RaGYABo4BvkGomsevrhQ41MYc1MlCcmpsor0qpr6k6MTMwsAGFzBZRDJzKtLutrsA5JonnAAIJQKBYPAvV5vGafOY-Bp-e6PACicOAkMx0JKtAgcmChShFOmHxQX3mvzuALJnQZmI2W12BM5x1Ocg6NAazlcXPFPn8gWlJ2isXl5x50gAlNyKeqSGsNVq4Druer2GxhOZVHAAGbZJRZHK+ADaDQGS1EDQAus7bv8HhZlJ6gA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to exclude `null` from the type of `project`:

```
let foo: NonNullable<Foobar['project']>['milestones']
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=33&ssc=1&pln=31&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCyBDRAjYAeAFQD44BeOAuAHzgDsBXAG0YG4AoNpFOABSggBWwAMbxyAbzZw4ASwAmALjgBnGFBm0A5mwC+HLqjQzGwVRFqoJU2YpVqN26TBkwTS1eq3XVGWABEMGGAlBgBbXChrYFo5AKCQ+nDgSL1OZFQAMQgIbF8yOAAKa3E4AH1Sg1oMUOAAfiUAcgBFemTEBrg9aQAyOBKwfiFRJUwcfCLpaRLyyuq6xr5BERgOrsnenhlhAGs8RaGYABo4BvkGomsevrhQ41MYc1MlCcmpsor0qpr6k6MTMwsAGFzBZRDJzKtLutrsA5JonnAAIJQKBYPAvV5vGafOY-Bp-e6PACicOAkMx0JKtAgcmChShFOmHxQX3mvzuALJnQZmI2W12BM5x1Ocg6NAazlcXPFPn8gWlJ2isXl5x50gAlNyKeqSGsNVq4Druer2GwTPAAGbZJQAOXMNqYjAw2BMeCyOV8AG0GgMlqIGgBdIje27-B4WZSBoA)